# RStudios - Dplyr - Using aggregation, How do I get an output similar to the guide I'm following?

Tags: r, twitter, dplyr

I'm trying to do some twitter analysis using r studios and I came across a certain section of the guide where it aggregates a few columns together. Where I group the persons name, and summarise the mean of the users followers and friends.
On the guide it shows this

[image: Pic 1]

However, when I try to repeat the exact same code on to my r studios, It instead,
shows me the following output. Why doesn't it show the "screen_name" column and it somehow takes the mean of all the rows?

[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that `plyr` also got loaded along with `dplyr` and the `plyr::summarise` masked the `dplyr::summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>%
    plyr::summarise(Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width))
 # Sepal.Width
 #1    3.057333
```

---

An option is to either do this on a fresh `R` session with `dplyr` only loaded or use `dplyr::` explicitly to avoid getting masked

```
iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     dplyr::summarise(Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    Sepal.Width
#  <fct>            <dbl>
#1 setosa            3.43
#2 versicolor        2.77
#3 virginica         2.97
```

Comment: You are correct!! Thanks a lot for this, I thought I was going mad. So with the dplyr:: command, I could use this for other libraries if they have similar functions?  This is very useful, thank you!

Comment: @Q.T.π You can do this for most of the functions

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to un-run a library, or would I have to close it and open it again?

Comment: @Q.T.π You can comment out by `#` at the beginning of that line that holds the library

Comment: @Q.T.π  You can also do an assignment `summarise <- dplyr::summarise` and then use `summarise` to override the masking